# Apache throws 401 Unauthorized

Tags: apache, location, virtualhost, unauthorized, errordocument

This is my `VirtualHost` configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

     ServerName example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public

     <Directory /var/www/example.com/public>
             Options +FollowSymLinks
             AllowOverride All
             Require user user1 user2
     </Directory>

     <Location /error/401>
             Require all granted
     </Location>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.error.log
     LogLevel warn
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.access.log combined

     ErrorDocument 500 /error/500
     ErrorDocument 404 /error/404
     ErrorDocument 401 /error/401

</VirtualHost>
```

But still when I intentionally fail authentication (or when I directly open /error/401), I get this:

```
Unauthorized

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

Additionally, a 401 Unauthorized error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

What am I doing wrong? According to the doc linked below, `Location` should be processed after `Directory` so this should work.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/sections.html#merging

**EDIT:**

Just so it's clear, this is the problematic part:

```
Additionally, a 401 Unauthorized error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what the problem is but it seems like Apache is working normally.  "when I intentionally fail authentication" should take you to the 401 page, and when you try to browse to "/error/401" it should also take you to the 401 page.  So, does it work when you enter a valid username and password?

Comment: This is the problematic part: "Additionally, a 401 Unauthorized error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request."

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?  Apache 2.2 and 2.4 have some differences with regard to access control: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: I'm using 2.4. You can see in my config I'm using `Require all granted`. I don't think that's even valid syntax in 2.2 so I don't think I would be able to start 2.2 with it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a very similar problem. The key practical issue being that upon failing authentication at the DocumentRoot level of the site the custom error page, which resides below the DocumentRoot (i.e. /error/401), cannot be accessed so instead the default Apache error message is issued.

The solution I went with was to incorporate html into the ErrorDocument 401 directive. For example
 `ErrorDocument 401 "INSERT MARKUP HERE"`  
 
(note quotes around your markup are essential).

Granted this is very much a workaround.